# CakePHP SQL-query count for maximum review

Tags: php, count, cakephp-2.3

How can I count the review so that I can display according to popularity, i.e who has highest review to show first and so on. Which venue has highest review, it will show first and then the rests follow. I have tried this but it is not working.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Venue] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                )
            [Review] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 9
                            [rating] => 4
                            [venue_id] => 6
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 10
                            [rating] => 3
                            [venue_id] => 6
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 11
                            [rating] => 3
                            [venue_id] => 6
                        )
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Venue] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 15
                )
            [Review] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 16
                            [rating] => 5
                            [venue_id] => 15
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 17
                            [rating] => 4
                            [venue_id] => 15
                        )
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [Venue] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 17
                )
            [Review] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 15
                            [rating] => 4
                            [venue_id] => 17
                        )
                )
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [Venue] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 31
                )
            [Review] => Array
                (
                )
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [Venue] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 32
                )
            [Review] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 18
                            [rating] => 1
                            [venue_id] => 32
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 19
                            [rating] => 1
                            [venue_id] => 32
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 20
                            [rating] => 1
                            [venue_id] => 32
                        )
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 21
                            [rating] => 1
                            [venue_id] => 32
                        )
                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 22
                            [rating] => 1
                            [venue_id] => 32
                        )
                )
        )
)

      if ($order == 'popularity') {
            $order = array('COUNT(Review) DESC');
        }
        $this->Paginator->settings = array('conditions' => $conditions, 'limit' => 10, 'order' => $order, 'page' => @$data['page']);
        $sqql = $this->Paginator->paginate('Venue');
```

Comment: Read the manual? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-count Also *always* tag the specific CakePHP version you're using.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to fix some grammar and to improve formatting. I also indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properlyvand I removed many spare empty lines - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in to provide additional details that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i did it simply by writing 2 line coding in model of given controller .I have found this the best way to do it using "Virtualfield" concept  in cakephp.

```
   var $virtualFields = array(
    'review_count' => 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reviews as Review WHERE Review.venue_id = Venue.id'
);
```

After using Virtualfield concept ,it seems too easier .

Here the result will come like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Venue] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [review_count]=> 3
                )
         )
[1] => Array
        (
            [Venue] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 15
                    [review_count]=>2
                )
        )
[2] => Array
        (
            [Venue] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 17
                    [review_count]=>1
                )
        )
[3] => Array
        (
            [Venue] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 31
                    [review_count]=>0
                )
        )
[4] => Array
        (
            [Venue] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 32
                    [review_count]=>5
                )
        )
```

Here one can easily find the nunber of reviews for a certain id.
Thank you